# lateinit property onItemClickCallback has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, kotlin-lateinit

I'm newbie on android and kotlin. I'm making onclick listener for my cardViewAdapter using interface so i can override its callback from my activity. But I get the error "lateinit property onItemClick has not been initialized" when running it on emulator and clicked each itemView.

On my code, I tried to initialize it inside a function. Before that, I tried this answer from another so https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076355/7587265
but onclick doesn't work

this is my MainActivity.kt

```
rvMotor.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
val recycleViewAdapter = CardViewMainAdapter(listMotor)
recycleViewAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object : CardViewMainAdapter.OnItemClickCallback{
    override fun onItemClicked(data: Motor) {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, DetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_ID, data.id)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
})

rvMotor.adapter = recycleViewAdapter
```

and this is my CardViewMainAdapter.kt

```
class CardViewMainAdapter(private val listMotors: ArrayList<Motor>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewMainAdapter.CardViewMainViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var onItemClickCallback : OnItemClickCallback

    fun setOnItemClickCallback(onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback){
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewMainViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cardview_main, parent, false)
        return CardViewMainViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listMotors.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewMainViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val motor = listMotors[position]

        holder.cvMainName.text = motor.name
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(motor.image)
            .apply(RequestOptions().override(350, 550))
            .into(holder.cvMainImage)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(listMotors[holder.adapterPosition])
        }
    }

    inner class CardViewMainViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var cvMainImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_main_img)
        var cvMainName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_main_txt)
    }

    interface OnItemClickCallback {
        fun onItemClicked(data: Motor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up initializing onItemClickCallback inside adapter parameter, not from function. I thought i've tried this way, but for an unknown reason, it doesn't work before. Thanks for all responses.
this is my activity

```
val recycleViewAdapter = CardViewMainAdapter(listMotor, object : CardViewMainAdapter.OnItemClickCallback{
            override fun onItemClicked(data: Motor) {
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, DetailActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_ID, data.id)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        })

rvMotor.adapter = recycleViewAdapter
```

this is my adapter

```
class CardViewMainAdapter(private val listMotors: ArrayList<Motor>, private val onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewMainAdapter.CardViewMainViewHolder>() {
```

Answer (score 1):

**As per the doc :** Accessing a lateinit property before it has been initialized throws a special exception that clearly identifies the property being accessed and the fact that it hasn't been initialized.

To check whether a lateinit var has already been initialized, 
use **.isInitialized** on the reference to that property:

I don't why it's causing the problem here. Your code is fine I think, but I can give you solution to your problem.

**In your case you can solve your problem in two ways.**

**1.** 
Just add an if condition in on clicks listener to check whether it is intilized or not.

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{

        //Check whether it is Initialized or not
        if(::onItemClickCallback.isInitialized){
            onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(listMotors[holder.adapterPosition])
        }
    }
```

**OR**

**2.** remove lateint and make it as nullable.

```
    //Make it as nullable
    private  var onItemClickCallback : OnItemClickCallback? = null

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            // add ? for handling nullable 
            onItemClickCallback?.onItemClicked(listMotors[holder.adapterPosition])
        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you for your advice, I ended up with declaring onItemClickCallback inside adapter parameter

Comment: Okay, That's great to hear that you solved your problem.