# lateinit property viewModel not initialized when calling a method on click from RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

I'm trying to delete a note from a Room Database by calling a method when the user long clicks 
on the note, I set up the onLongClickListener on the RView adapter:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnCLickListener{
            NotesFragment().deleteSingleNote(notesID)
        }
```

On NotesFragment, the method looks like:

```
fun deleteSingleNote(notesID: Long) {
        notesFragmentViewModel.deleteSingleNoteFromDB(notesID)
    }
```

and on the ViewModel the method deletes the note through a coroutine.

The app crashes on long click, saying that the lateinit notesFragmentViewModel had not been initializing, pointing to the onLongCLickListener line, and NotesFragment line I pasted above.

The thing is, the notes are populated on the screen through a NotesFragmentViewModel LiveData variable which contains all the notes, so the ViewModel is very much initialized by the time I long click on the item.

I tried initializing the ViewModel on the adapter, but I got an exception related to ViewModel not being allowed tobe instantialized on something other than a fragment/activity.

This is my first post on SOverflow, so please let me know if I did anything wrong

Comment: `lateinit property viewModel not initialized` this means that your viewModel isn't initialized, never being assigned a value, basically a null on something which should not be null, look at where you assign a value to the viewModel and you'll have your answer

Comment: Yes, I know that, I don't know why it says it is not initialized, since the very item I long clicked on was populated using a variable from this same ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `OnClickListener` you want to access the `NotesFragment` instance which is currently displayed. But with `NotesFragment()` you create a new instance of `NotesFragment`. Since it will not be attached to any `Activity` it's very likely that the  *notesFragmentViewModel* property of the new instance has not been initialized.

So to avoid an `Exception` *you have to access the correct instance* of `NotesFragment`. You could introduce a parameter of type `NotesFragment` to the constructor of the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, but this is considered bad practice.

It's better to let the adapter class have an interface (let's call it `ListItemClickedListener`) and a constructor which requires an instance of `ListItemClickedListener` as parameter.

```
interface ListItemClickedListener{
    fun singleNoteLongClicked(notesID: Long)
}
```

Then you can have either `NotesFragment` implement `ListItemClickedListener` and pass itself to the adapter or you use an anonymous local instance of `ListItemClickedListener`.

Inside the adapter:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnCLickListener{
    listItemClickListener.singleNoteLongClicked(notesID)
}
```

In `NotesFragment`:

```
override fun singleNoteLongClicked(notesID: Long){
    this@NotesFragment.deleteSingleNote(notesID)
}
```

See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076148/how-to-create-onclick-event-in-adapter-using-interface-android) for an implementation of this pattern.

Comment: Will I be using ListItemClickListener as the long click listener of the adapter? Or rather, what will I use this ListItemClickListener for?

Comment: @Sir -  I'll edit my answer and add some code snippets